# PHPUnit testing a protected method that calls a private method which needs to be mocked

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

I am trying to write a unit test for a protected method which I am aware that I can use reflection class to achieve this. The problem is that, this protected method calls two private methods and I need to mock those private methods (I have my reasons for this). Is this even possible?

Here is my class:

```
class MyClass
{
    protected function myProtectedMethod(string $argOne, int $argTwo)
    {
        $privateMethodOneValue = $this->privateMethodOne($argOne);
        $privateMethodTwoValue = $this->privateMethodTwo($argTwo);

        // Some more logic below that is unrelated to the question
    }

    private function privateMethodOne(string $arg): string
    {
        // does some laravel specific stuff that can't be unit tested in PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
        // this is why it was abstracted out from the protected method, to make unit testing possible
    }

    private function privateMethodTwo(int $arg): int
    {
        // does some laravel specific stuff that can't be unit tested in PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
        // this is why it was abstracted out from the protected method, to make unit testing possible
    }
}
```

In my test, I have something like this:

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class MyClassTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testMyProtectedMethod()
    {
        $mmyMockClass = $this->getMockBuilder(Controller::class)
            ->onlyMethods(['privateMethodOne', 'privateMethodTwo'])
            ->getMock();
        
        $reflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass($mmyMockClass);

        $privateMethodOne = $reflectionClass->getMethod('privateMethodOne');
        $privateMethodOne->setAccessible(true);

        $privateMethodTwo = $reflectionClass->getMethod('privateMethodTwo');
        $privateMethodTwo->setAccessible(true);

        $myProtectedMethod = $reflectionClass->getMethod('myProtectedMethod');
        $myProtectedMethod->setAccessible(true);
        
        $mockArgOne = 'some argument string';
        $mockArgTwo = 99999;

        $privateMethodOneResult = 'some result string';
        $privateMethodTwoResult = 88888;
        
        $mmyMockClass->expects($this->once())
            ->method('privateMethodOne')
            ->with($mockArgOne)
            ->willReturn($privateMethodOneResult);

        $mmyMockClass->expects($this->once())
            ->method('privateMethodTwo')
            ->with($mockArgTwo)
            ->willReturn($privateMethodTwoResult);
        
        $result = $myProtectedMethod->invoke($reflectionClass, $mockArgOne, $mockArgTwo);
        
        // some assertions here
    }
}
```

but obviously this doesn't work. I am getting errors for the private methods I am trying to mock. Here is what the error looks like:
`Trying to configure method "privateMethodOne" which cannot be configured because it does not exist, has not been specified, is final, or is static`

I've read a lot of articles, posts about this and I know that generally it's a bad practice to try to unit test private methods, and/or it's a bad design if you find yourself that you have to test it. I understand all of that and if there is more about that I need to read that's welcome as well, but, I, at least am trying to understand if this is even possible, and would love to learn how if it is.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: If it does some "Laravel stuff", then I would say do not use `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` and just use `Laravel's TestCase`, it is okay to use it when you are testing your code. If you do this, you can use dependency injection (using the Service Container) or maybe fake a facade so you can still mock anything. Could you add more info about what "Laravel stuff" you have in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$result = $myProtectedMethod->invoke($reflectionClass, $mockArgOne, $mockArgTwo);`

should be

`$result = $myProtectedMethod->invoke($mmyMockClass, $mockArgOne, $mockArgTwo);`

For more information how to use "invoke" method here. https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.invoke.php

Comment: Could you edit your answer to further explain how/why this answers their question?